# Align Font Awesome icon vertically centred and to left of table

Tags: css, html, sass, font-awesome

I am trying to position a font-awesome icon to the left of a table element, such that it is vertically centred against the table.

This is what I have at the moment:

**HTML**

```
<div class="dates">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <table>
         <tbody>
             <tr>
                 <td>24th Jul 2018</td>
                 <td>7PM</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>25th Jul 2018</td>
                <td>7PM</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td>26th Jul 2018</td>
                 <td>7PM</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td>27th Jul 2018</td>
                 <td>1PM / 7PM</td>
             </tr>
        </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.dates {
    border: 3px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    border-color: grey;

    .fa {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    table {
         display: inline-block;

         td {
              font-weight: bold;
              margin: 0;
              padding: 0 10px;
         }
    }
}
```

And it's giving me this result:

[image: Icon not vertically centred next to the table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle` to both the icon and table, like so:

(For the purposes of the demo I unnested your Sass into normal CSS.)

```css
.dates {
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  border-color: grey;
}

.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

table {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

td {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div class="dates">
  <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>24th Jul 2018</td>
        <td>7PM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>25th Jul 2018</td>
        <td>7PM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>26th Jul 2018</td>
        <td>7PM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>27th Jul 2018</td>
        <td>1PM / 7PM</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: That's perfect, thanks for your help! Just so I'm clear, must the icon be ```display: inline-block``` because the table is? I'm just trying to understand the solution.

Comment: That's about it, yes. I'd recommend reading this article, specifically the "Requirements to Use Vertical-Align" section: http://christopheraue.net/2014/03/05/vertical-align/